# How can add multiple tiles image in ReactOpenSeadragon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openseadragon

Here ith code i am trying But its not working

```
class App extends Component {

  state =
  {
    id: "OSD",
    getImageURL: 'http://cdm16022.contentdm.oclc.org/utils/ajaxhelper',
    osdConfig: {
      setStrings: [{ name: 'Tooltips.Home', value: 'Reset' }],
      defaultZoomLevel: 0,
      tileSources: [
        {
          Image: {
            xmlns: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/deepzoom/2008",
            Url: "https://openseadragon.github.io/example-images/highsmith/highsmith_files/",
            Format: "jpg",
            Overlap: "0",
            TileSize: "256",
            Size: {
              Height: "9221",
              Width: "7026"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          Image: {
            xmlns: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/deepzoom/2008",
            Url: "https://openseadragon.github.io/example-images/highsmith/highsmith_files/",
            Format: "jpg",
            Overlap: "1",
            TileSize: "256",
            Size: {
              Height: "621",
              Width: "526"
            }
          }
        }

      ],
    },
    pages: [
      {
        id: 0,
      },
      {
        id: 1,
      }

    ],
  };






  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Slider click={this.clickSlider} />
        <div className="wrapper">
        </div>
        <ReactOpenSeadragon {...this.state} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ReactOpenSeadragon, but I have a few observations at the OpenSeadragon level. Those two tileSources will be stacked directly over top of each other unless you position them somehow. The easiest way is to add `collectionMode: true` to your options (to have them appear next to each other) or `sequenceMode: true` (to have them appear as pages that you can navigate to using arrow buttons in the UI).

Also `defaultZoomLevel: 0` seems wrong; zoom should never be 0. Maybe just remove that entirely for now.